# How to write a loop that creates ts objects and stores them separately as such?

Tags: r, loops, time-series

I am analysing time series data of plant biomass/ rain use efficiency. I have a data set with a response variable and several factors (grazing intensities) as well as replicates for each factor (4 factors, 5 or 7 replicates) . 
I need to create time series objects out of each individual dataset that comprises yearly data from 1981 until 2007. I have 24 individual assessments of different plots over this time.

I am trying to write a loop for this but am failing miserably.

The dataset is called dat. 
PMR6yrs is the response variable.
ID is the ID of the replicate.
somehow it returns only one ts object in the end so I think the problem lies in storing them.

What I tried so far is this:

```
tsPMR<- NULL
for (i in 1:24) {
tsPMR6<- ts(dat$PMR_6yrs[dat$ID == i],
start = c(1981), end = c(2007), frequency = 1)
ts<-rbind(tsPMR, tsPMR6)
}
```

Can someone assist? thanks sm

Comment: Use `tsPMR<-rbind(tsPMR, tsPMR6)` instead of `ts<-rbind(tsPMR, tsPMR6)`

Comment: Thanks so much! haha its always the small things :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its hard to see what the issue is on you code (usually its nice to have data so we can reproduce the problem).  But don't you need to be binding to the object tsPMR

```
tsPMR<- NULL
for (i in 1:24) {
tsPMR6<- ts(dat$PMR_6yrs[dat$ID == i],
start = c(1981), end = c(2007), frequency = 1)
tsPMR<-rbind(tsPMR, tsPMR6)
}

print( tsPMR )
```

you can also add an assign statement in your loop - that would create 24 different objects for each iteration of the loop

```
assign ( paste0("tsPMR6", i ) , tsPMR6)
```

@nicola - is right, you should avoid assign.  the edit made to the loop should fix your rbind issue

Comment: Two comments. 1) Growing objects inside a loop is a very bad practice (see for instance the R inferno, chapter 2: https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf). 2) The use of `assign` should be totally discouraged. It's a bad practice that pollutes your workspace with no upside. It's much better here to build a list at the top of the loop and then `rbind` all the list together.

Comment: @nicola - i agree.  the fix to the rbind is clearly the easier and safer solution

Comment: thanks so much. OMG can't believe how small things can fix everything! THANKS!